# Show Hidden Elements in JasperSoft 4.0 Report when Exporting to Excel

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I created a report in iReport 4.02.  I have a few text fields in the header band that I would like to hide when viewing on JasperServer 4.0, but display when the user exports the report to Excel (or any other format).

Is there a variable or parameter I can use that specifies if the report is being exported or not?  I can use this variable or parameter in the "Print When Expression".

Comment: Are you exporting from JasperServer, or an application?

Comment: Exporting the report from the JasperServer using the "Export" dropdown.